# Too many filters - You can only create up to 20 field filters : on a Tabular Report

Tags: reporting, force.com, salesforce-id

I am creating a Tabular report on Contacts.
Contacts object has got many customized fields as well.
I want to list few details of all my contacts (contact of type 'Student') who has got certain fields (around 23) non-empty.

I started adding the filters as below..

Filter Logic: 1 AND (2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10 OR 11 OR 12 OR 13 OR 14 OR 15 OR 16 OR 17 OR 18 OR 19 OR 20)
1. Contact Record Type equals "Student"
2. Career Interests not equal to ""
3. Career Interest Details not equal to ""
 :
 :
20. Preference in Country to travel to not equal to ""

Now on adding any further filter for remaining fields, I get the following message:
"Too many filters - You can only create up to 20 field filters"

Can someone please guide me, how I could create these report as I have around 24 filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a formula field on the contact object that checks if all the fields you are looking at are blank and filter on that field and the contact recordtype.

formula field:

```
IF(
NOT(AND(
 ISBLANK( field1__c),
 ISBLANK( field2__c),
 ISBLANK( field3__c),
 ...
)),
'true',
'false')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any other way/solution of achieving this, possibly without adding formula field to Contacts object?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: thanks all! we removed few less important filters, but your solution is useful for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

you can also bundle together filters that are on the same field and use comma separated values like

field1_*c equals 1,2,3,4
field2*_c equals "this", "that"

that should save you some space

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have too many fields and only test I want to do is that they are non-empty.

Comment: Yea in that case the formula is your best bet.