# Why does my Salesforce instance only allow number, currency, or percent as the output type from a row level formula?

Tags: reporting, formula, custom-reports

Building on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3535/104740) in a report, I'm testing out row level formulas applied to strings, columns, etc. When I try to simple row level formula of `ISNUMBER('text')`, I get this error:

> Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Number).

But, as circled in the screenshot, Salesforce only allows me to use number, currency, or percent as the output type of the formula. This is in a summary report (since row level formulas aren't allowed in tabular reports, I don't think).

This is all a test to build row level formulas that basically check if multiple variables are missing and create a new column with that output, so I can get around the restriction on the number of filters allowed in a report.

I'm using Salesforce Enterprise Edition. The screenshot is from the classic editor but use Lightning Experience too. API version is 42.0.

[image: screenshot of error message and allowed format types in Salesforce]

Comment: the short answer is the formula result can only be shown at summary and grand total levels and thus is inherently an arithmetic operation.  Your formula should return either a 1 or a 0 so wrap the ISNUMBER in an IF

Comment: @cropredy Not in front of my instance at the moment, but this should work, no? `IF(ISBLANK([OCR_Opportunity].Date_of_Birth__c), 1, 0)` (picking an arbitrary field name that's in the report)

Comment: @cropredy What are answers like this answer referring to, when they say to change the formula output type to Text? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/123500/104740

Comment: the answers in that question make the assumption that summary formulas can return TEXT - but as you state, they can not; Note answers were not accepted